# Spring Boot & Hibernate: MySQL TEXT with local h2 and Flyway

Tags: mysql, spring, h2, flyway

I am building a Spring Boot application which has several long texts in it's entities.

To ensure I can handle my database migrations well I included Flyway. In production I'm using a MySQL database, for local testing I want to implement the default h2 database.

An entity might have the following property

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
val startText: String?
```

For my MySQL database, this works fine and looks like this in my flyway schema:

`start_text  TEXT,`

When I now start my tests with the default h2 in-memory database in Spring, I receive the following error:

```
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [start_text] in table [t_table]; found [clob (Types#CLOB)], but expecting [text (Types#VARCHAR)]
```

I understand that h2 does not support the MySQL specific type `TEXT` but actually I have no clue how to fix this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for this.
In my application.yaml I have the following:

```
spring:
  flyway:
    placeholders:
      text-datatype: 'TEXT' #defines a placeholder that is available in flyway
```

In my application.yaml in my test folder I have the following

```
spring:
  flyway:
    placeholders:
      text-datatype: 'VARCHAR(255)'
```

Now I can use the placeholder in my Flyway scripts and it works fine:

`start_text ${text-datatype}`